# Disk Space requirement for Xcode on a Solid State Drive (SSD)

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, xcode, ssd

I have a question on the storage requirement for running Xcode and working on Application development.

I am planning on upgrading my Macbook Hard disk to a Solid State Drive (SSD) for an increase in speed. Would it be enough if I have a 128GB SSD , or should I go for the 256GB SSD (which is more expensive) ? Could anyone help me with this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode and iOS SDK takes up around 10.5 GB of hard drive space. Depending on how much other space you plan to use up, I suppose a 128 GB hard drive is enough.